# new Intent with ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, listadapter

I have a `ListView` loading project data from an XML-File

```
for (int i = 0; i < nlProject.getLength(); i++) {

            // Neue HashMap erstellen
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nlProject.item(i);

            // Jedes Kind-Knoten zur HashMap
            map.put(KEY_UUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UUID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_JOBTITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBTITLE));
            map.put(KEY_JOBINFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBINFO));
            map.put(KEY_PROJECT_IMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PROJECT_IMAGE));


            //Hashmap zur ArrayList hinzufügen
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item_projects,
                new String[]{KEY_JOBTITLE, KEY_JOBINFO},
                new int[]{R.id.jobtitle, R.id.jobinfo});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

if I click on an item I want to load a new window displaying my task-data

Here is the code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    //Neue Oberfläche starten
    Intent in = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, ListMenuItemActivity.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE,"title");
    in.putExtra(KEY_INFO,"info");
    in.putExtra(KEY_LOCATION, "location");
    startActivity(in);


    ListAdapter taskadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item_tasks,
            new String[]{KEY_TITLE, KEY_INFO, KEY_OBJECT, KEY_LOCATION},
            new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.info, R.id.object, R.id.location});

    setListAdapter(taskadapter);
```

The problem is that it change the ListAdapter(adapter) to taskadapter instead of creating a new activity/intent

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: why are you changing the adapter in the click method after starting the new activity

Comment: oh it's wrong. it have to be reverse. first changing the adapter and then the new activity

Comment: Ok, so why are you changing the adapter if you are going to jump to a different activity?

Comment: i want that my new activity displays the adapter. the taskadapter have the informations i want to display on a new intent. is it maybe a wrong way to display it?

Comment: Yes thats the wrong way of doing it. You can pass the List adapter values you want like the string and the int array in the EXTRAS to your new Activity then there you can make the list adapter and set the ListActivity's adapter to it

Comment: oh okay that's the right way thank you. How can i pass the string and int arrays to my new Activity? Maybe:         in.putExtra("intArray",new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.info,R.id.object,R.id.location});

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a String array as an extra by using `putStringArrayList(String key, ArrayList<String> value)` method; for example,

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
stringArray.add("The String value you want");
stringArray.add("Another String value you want");
```

And for the Int array by using `putIntArray(String key, int[] value)` method also check this li[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) for reference about `EXTRA` fields.

Comment: in.putStringArrayListExtra("stringArray",ArrayList<String> KEY_TITLE ); Something is missing and i don't know what :/

Comment: Well you make an ArrayList of Strings the strings that you want, i've edited the answer check how to make an ArrayList and how to add values to it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

As replied in the comments above you have to write only the code to open the activity.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    //Neue Oberfläche starten
    Intent in = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, ListMenuItemActivity.class);
    in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE,"title");
    in.putExtra(KEY_INFO,"info");
    in.putExtra(KEY_LOCATION, "location");
    startActivity(in);
});
```

You can then set the list adapter in new activity

```
ListAdapter taskadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item_tasks,
            new String[]{KEY_TITLE, KEY_INFO, KEY_OBJECT, KEY_LOCATION},
            new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.info, R.id.object, R.id.location});

    setListAdapter(taskadapter);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: The Problem then is, that it can't find menuItems and the Strings because it's in my ListViewActivity. The ListAdapter have to be in the new Activity right? in that case in my ListMenuItemActivity?

Comment: how can i access then to menuItems and to both arrays? :/